# In using multiple storyboards after button on click why do I get window hierarchy error?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I am following an approach to use multiple storyboards here:
http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/organizing-xcode-projects-using-multiple-storyboards/

But I want to switch storyboards after the user presses a button, 
and the error I get is:

> Warning: Attempt to present SWRevealViewController on
>   MainViewController view is not in the window hierarchy!

The code to switch storyboards is:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Search", bundle: nil)
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("theRealID") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

FYI, I AM able to load the second storyboard if I do this, but....this is not when I want it. I want it after button press.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Search", bundle: nil)
    var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("theRealID") as! UIViewController

    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What is "self" in that code? Is MainViewController's view on screen when the user presses the button?

Comment: Yes. I can load the other storyboard in viewDidAppear, but not after button press.

Comment: Are you doing anything else other than the code you show in the button' action method?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an IBAction for your button and instantiate a new view controller as follow:

```
presentViewController( UIStoryboard(name: "Search", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("theRealID") as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you want you can also use it with a navigation controller:

```
presentViewController( UIStoryboard(name: "Search", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("theRealID") as! UINavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```